# Ubuntu 20.04 not allowing `runuser` to manage systemd --user services "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory"

Tags: systemd, users, bashrc, ps

When I try to run `runuser -l mruser -c "systemctl --user status myservice.service"` as root, I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I do not get this error when doing the same on a RHEL 8.4 system. I am able to run systemd --user commands as mruser using runuser with no problems.

**Troubleshooting Performed:**

- tried running `systemctl --user status myservice.service` as `mruser` command runs with no errors.
- I already checked loginctl for `mruser`, `Linger=yes`
- Checked to make sure there was a `systemd --user` process running with `ps`
- Logged into the user's account directly with separate ssh session, Then tried the same command as root in the original session, still same error.
- `mruser` already has `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` in `~/.bashrc`
- Tried rebooting the system, still nothing.
- Already read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374347/error-running-systemd-as-user-failed-to-connect-to-bus-dbus-session-bus-addr), was not very helpful.

On the RHEL system systemd is v239, On Ubuntu 20.04 its v245.
Am I missing something? Why can I not run the systemd --user commands as root on Ubuntu?

UPDATE: I think the issue has to do with `runuser` not seeing exported variables. which means `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not being recognized or used. Anyone know why runuser is not seeing exported variables defined in `mruser`'s `~/.bashrc` file? I checked the RHEL instance, and root IS able to see and use the exported variables.

Comment: It is not RHEL? Why something works on one OS and not Ubuntu is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: The problem occurs in Ubuntu. The problem does not occurs on RHEL. 
Even if it does not happen RHEL, the problem happens on Ubuntu. Why would that escape the scope of this site?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the `~/.bashrc` file for myuser.
On Ubuntu the default `.bashrc` file has the following line:

```
case $- in
      *i*);;
        *) return;;
esac
```

This is not in the RHEL default `.bashrc` file. This case statement is looking for the parameter `bash -i` to be used. Without it the shell is not interactive and `.bashrc` is not used, ergo, The defined `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is never seen, so `systemd --user` command fails.

I have not figured out a way to get `runuser` force this case statement to recognize sending a `-i`.

**Work around:** I removed these lines with this command:

```
sed -i '/case $- in/,/esac/ s/^/# /' /home/mruser/.bashrc
```

After doing so, running `runuser` as root on Ubuntu works as expected.
If anyone knows of a way to get this case statement to recognize `-i` with `runuser` please share, I will update this solution. But for now this is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`) when running the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

`systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`

The problem was because of the alias:

`alias systemctl='sudo systemctl'`

It substituted the `systemctl` with `sudo systemctl` and sudo caused the error.