# systemctl: Failed to connect to bus

Tags: systemd, services, xscreensaver

On Ubuntu 22.04, I'm trying to set up `xscreensaver` as a daemon using `systemctl`.  Following [these instructions](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-autostart-xscreensaver-ubuntu-18-04-19-04), I've created the following at `~/.config/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=XScreenSaver
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xscreensaver -nosplash
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and run

```sh
systemctl --user enable xscreensaver
```

However, I get the error

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

I saw [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374348/699281) and tried

```sh
systemctl --user --global enable xscreensaver
```

That worked.  However, when I tried to start the service with

```sh
systemctl --user --global start xscreensaver
```

I got the `Failed to connect to bus` error again.

Comment: Related: [Unable to create SystemD user service "Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1470010/968501) ... Bus addresses(*inter-processes communication paths*) are handled by a socket file that is part of the user-runtime environment that should be available first ... Read the **notice** part in my answer to the linked post above.