# I tried running " sudo -i " but not working

Tags: command-line

I tried running `sudo -i`   but not working keeps saying :-

> Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=@.host --user to connect to bus of other user.

[Here is the message i receive after the prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW11Q.png)

Please help thanks :)

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the command to do? the prompt string suggests it *is* giving you a root login shell - the errors suggest an issue with your root account's shell configuration. Have you added stuff to `/root/.bashrc` or `/root/.profile`?

Comment: I want to use the command to upgrade my permission level because some other commands won´t run unless that error is fixed.But i´ve not added nothing to  `/root/.bashrc`  or `/root/.profile` please teach me how to.

Comment: What about `/etc/{prof,bash}*`? You can also try resetting your root user with `sudo bash -c 'mv /root /root.bak; mkdir /root; chmod 700 /root'`

Comment: I tried the first command `/etc/{prof,bash}*` it was denied and the other command `sudo bash -c 'mv /root /root.bak; mkdir /root; chmod 700 /root'` couldn´t fix it.

Comment: The first wasn't a command. I was asking you whether you modified the files /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc or anything inside /etc/profile.d . Please also make sure you did not change any files or directories starting with "sudo" inside /etc. If in doubt, look at the last modified time

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374347/error-running-systemd-as-user-failed-to-connect-to-bus-dbus-session-bus-addr

Comment: @Rinzwind In that question, they are trying to have root start a daemon as a user. In this question, `sudo -i` shouldn't require connecting to the user systemd instance. The "quick solution" part of the top answer there somewhat introduces a security hazard. I don't think it's related.